# Boolean vs non-boolean search

Tags: algorithm, search, full-text-search, search-engine, information-retrieval

I'm having some issues trying to understand what a non-boolean search (if that makes sense) is. As far as I've figured out, a boolean search allows the use of AND, OR and NOT in the query. But what about the non-boolean search? I've read somewhere that that means you can search substrings, not just complete words, but I wanted to make sure I fully understand what each of one means. Also, maybe an example would help, like, is Google boolean or non-boolean? What about Oracle Text or Apahe Solr?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non boolean search includes approaches that are not purely boolean model techniques<sup>1</sup>.

Probably the most common example of such a method is the [**vector-space model**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space_model).

In this model, each document is a vector, represented by the words (or bi-grams,...) it contains. The dimension of each document is the number of terms in the vocabulary.

The similarity in this model is done by creating a 'fake' document - which is the query, and comparing this fake document to any other document in the corpus. The more similar the document is to the query - the better the result is.

A common similarity measure is [cosine-similarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity).

This model goes well with the [tf-idf model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) (The td-idf determines what is the value in each entry of each vector).

Note that this is NOT boolean model. You do not oporate on 'sets', you compare similarity of vectors - this is entirely different model.

In addition, this method has an important advantage - it returns a score associated to each document, and not only a boolean answer "relevant" or "not relevant".

As-is vector-space does not allow AND,OR oporations, however this is easily solveable by doing 2-phase search. The first is using a boolean model to get candidates, and the 2nd is using vector-space to get a score for each document.

---

Other models are building a [**language model**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_model) out of a document - a language model is described as `P(word|M) = the probability of the model M to generate the word`.

A common language model is `P(word|document) = #occurances(word,document)/|document|`

To avoid having probability zero - we usually add smoothing technique. a common technique is:

```
P(word|document) =  alpha*#occurances(word,document)/|document| + (1-alpha)*#occurances(word,corpus)/|corpus|
```

Now - when we have a query of more than one term: `q=t1 t2 ... tn`, we calculate:

```
P(q|d) = P(t1|d)*P(t2|d)*...*P(tn|d)
```

Note that this model actually allows AND semantics by setting `alpha=1`, and OR semantics by `alpha!=1`.

---

(1)
Boolean search is basically set terminology:

Each term is associated with a set that contains all the documents that have this term in them. Now, you simply do set oporations on bunch of sets. AND is intersection, OR is union.

Comment: Thanks, think I have it clearer now. So, would it be right to simplify it by saying that a non-boolean search sort of counts how many times a given term is found inside a document to see how relevant it is to the search?

Comment: @carcaret Usually yes, but it doesn't have to be the case. Once can use vector-space model with binary vectors. I personally see no benefit to it (as it is less informative than the alternative) - but it is possible.